# Wireshark plugin build with src code version 1.10.9 is not working with Wireshark 1.12.x

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have created a wireshark plugin of some protocol's dissector.
I used the source codes having version 1.10.9 to create the plugin.
The plugin is working fine with installed wireshark 1.10.9 or below versions.
But when I drop my dll file in plugins folder of installed wireshark with version 1.12.1, the wireshark.exe is no more launching.

It shows some error in a dialog box like "This application has caused some errors.....".

I used MSVC2010 to build the plugin and Wireshark Platform is win64.

Do I need to recompile the plugin everytime to make it work with latest higher version of Wireshark Application? Or Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to recompile. Your plugin should work against any version 1.10.*, but for 1.12 or any later "major" release the API has changed and your plugin will need to be rebuilt at the very least (it may also need minor updates to match the new API).